# Some issues about upgrade gcc to 4.9 in redhat

Tags: gcc

I'd like to install the gcc 4.9 for installing caffe, which is using for deep learning in redhat linux. When I run `./configure` ,it report

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables.
```

And then I check `configure.log`, it reports that

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux5E/lib64/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux5E/lib64/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
```

How can I fix this issue.It is too difficult for me to solve it.

Comment: I suspect you do not have all the necessary parts of glibc installed properly, you might need to install `glibc-devel` or the equivalent for rhel5, but you should also read https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: which version do i need to install glibc-devel,i tried it ,but it failed again

Comment: Whichever version is available as an rpm from the RH subscription service, via `yum` or whatever other method you use.

Comment: yum can't work due to the machine is not connected to intenet

Comment: Notice that I said "or whatever other method you use". Find the latest RPMs and install them.